# Using a variable after calling it from the function itself

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a variable created inside a function but when I call the function

I'm trying this :

```
def get_value():
    x = 1

get_value.x
```

But the value of x is not suggested.

Comment: as written get_value() doesn't return anything!!! the use of get_value.x is invalid, what do you get from your call?  What do you expect to get?

Comment: You can't access the variable inside a function. The variable doesn't exist until you call the function, and goes away when the function returns.

Comment: If you want to be able to access the value, the function should either return it or assign a global variable. You seem to be confusing functions with classes.

Comment: why do you think `.x` should be an *attribute* of the function? IOW, why did you ever expect `get_value.x` to work?

Comment: I understand that I can return the value, but why (because I use it during the creation of objects) is it part of the object, the function in this case or not...

Comment: Local variables are not part of the function. They're stored on the stack when the function is running.

Comment: Yes, functions are objects. You could do `get_value.x = 3` but that's unrelated to the local variable.

Comment: Consider that a function can be called multiple times and the local variable can have different values depending on the parameters. Which one of them should `get_value.x` return?

Answer (score 0):

That's not what functions do. When a function terminates, the local variables inside it stop existing. If you want to keep a value, the typical way is to return it.

```
def get_value():
    x = 1
    return x

my_value = get_value()
print(my_value)
```

If you want an object that stores values as fields, that's called a *class*, not a function. You can write a class to do it.

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

print(Value().x)
```

or a `@dataclass`, if all it's doing is storing data.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Value:
    x: int = 1

print(Value().x)
```

Comment: you might also want to show an example of a class attribute, that seems to be like what he wants.

Comment: I mean, you can write a class definition. You don't have to, functions are objects, and they are happy to accept attributes.

Answer (score 0):

That's because they are local variables and closed off from other functions. If you want to return a specific variable from a function, give the function the ability to return and apply any transformations on the variable necessary inside. i.e. If you have a function which just dictates that x = 1, then it should be:

```
def get_x(): 
   x = 1 
   return x
```

And then calling get_x() could return 1.

Alternatively, create an object, and make one of the particular parameters of that object returnable via a getter method. Good luck!

Comment: actually, none of this will make `get_x.x` not raise an AttributeError

Comment: That's invalid syntax.

Comment: "and make one of the particular parameters of that object returnable via a getter method" *no*. don't do that. don't write pointless getters. This is Python, not Java

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use `return x` to get the value back to the caller of `get_value()`.  However, if your purpose is to expose the content of local variables from the last function call.  You could store the locals in the function's dictionary before exiting it:

```
def get_value():
    x = 1
    get_value.__dict__.update(locals()) # expose locals of last call

get_value()
print(get_value.x) # 1
```